# Sending email with Flask errors with SMTPHandler

Tags: smtp, flask

I saw in the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/errorhandling/#error-mails) an extremely easy way to send emails on Flask errors. My question is whether this will considerably affect performance of the app? As in, is the process running my app actually sending the email?

My current hunch is that because SMTP is a server running on another process, it will enqueue the email properly and send it when it can, meaning it won't affect the performance of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [`SMTPHandler` inherits from `logging.Handler`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Lib/logging/handlers.py#l847).  Looking at [`logging.Handler`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l646), while it does several things to handle being *called* in multiple threads it doesn't do anything to *spawn* multiple threads.  The logging calls happen in the thread they are called on.  So, if I am reading the code correctly, a logging call will *block* the thread it is running on until it completes (which means that if your SMTP server takes 30 seconds to respond your erroring thread will take `time_to_error + 30 seconds + time_to_send + time_to_respond_to_request_with_500`.)

That said, I could be mis-reading the code.  However, you'd be better off using [`SysLogHandler`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Lib/logging/handlers.py#l636) and letting `syslog` handle sending you messages out of band.